# Halving a list into sublists using pattern matching

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get the output, given an input

```
> halve [1,2,3,4,5,6]
([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

I have solved this problem using this approach:

```
halve xs = ((take s xs), (drop s xs))
    where
      s = (length xs) `div` 2
```

I am a beginner in Haskell and I want to learn how to solve this question using pattern matching? Thanks

Comment: Hint: you can use a variant of the *hare and tortoise* algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection

Comment: Why do you want to use pattern matching for this problem? While possible, it seems like it would be way overkill to do here.

Comment: This is a question at the end of one of the exercises to learn haskell in our class, something like an extra question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of a variant of the [*hare and tortoise* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd's_Tortoise_and_Hare). This algorithm basically runs over the list with two iterators: the *hare* taking two hops at a time, and the *tortoise* performing one hop at that time.

When the hare reaches the end of the list, then we know that the tortoise is halfway, and thus can split the list in half: the list seen thus far is the first half, and the list still to enumerate over, is the second half.

An algorithm thus looks like:

```
half :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
half h = go h h
    where go (_:(_:hs)) (t:ts) = (..., ...)
              where (a, b) = go ...
          go _ (t:ts) = (..., ...)
          go _ [] = (..., ...)
```

with the `...` parts still to fill in.

Comment: How does `where (a, b) = go ...` work? Maybe I haven't seen that syntax yet.

Comment: @BradyDean" `go` returns a 2-tuple, so you call it recursively with the remaining of the lists for the hare and the tortoise, this will generate a 2-tuple of lists, `a` and `b`, and then you "post process" that 2-tuple, for example by prepending these lists with `t`, etc.

Comment: Ok makes sense now. I didn't see where `(a, b)` was being used but I do now.